# How to call CurrentUser in serializer from another serializer

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

I have 2 serializers and 1 serializer calling another where seriliazer has CurrentUserDefault but for some reason i've got an error `Not null Constraint Failed`

```
class IndividualClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    individual_user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = IndividualUser
        fields = ('individual_user', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class CardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = IndividualClientSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Cards
        fields = ('user',)
```

models.py

```
class Cards(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(IndividualUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='user_cards')

class IndividualUser(models.Model):
    individual_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                           primary_key=True, to_field='username', related_name='individual_user_user')
```

Comment: Can you add view please